# Mass delete file extension batch file

Tags: performance, file, batch-file, cmd, delete-file

Hello I have a batch file I've created to delete all files of a certain extension that it asks for when you run it.  I need to delete 2,111,000 .txt files and the batch file only deletes 3 at a time which will take forever to delete the files.  Is there a way I can make it faster or if somebody has a better code to do this?

Here is my code:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

SET found=0
ECHO Enter the file extension you want to delete...
SET /p ext="> "

IF EXIST *.%ext% (           rem Check if there are any in the current folder :)
DEL *.%ext%
SET found=1
)
FOR /D /R %%G IN ("*") DO (  rem Iterate through all subfolders
IF EXIST %%G CD %%G
IF EXIST *.%ext% (
DEL *.%ext%
SET found=1
)
)

IF %found%==1 (
ECHO.
ECHO Deleted all .%ext% files.
ECHO.
) ELSE (
ECHO.
ECHO There were no .%ext% files.
ECHO Nothing has been deleted.
ECHO.
)

PAUSE
EXIT
```

Can I make this go faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way I can imagine is just:

```
cd /BASE_PATH
del /s *.txt
```

You're probably better just letting the OS sequentially delete files rather than trying to delete multiple files in parallel anyways. If you're using a mechanical HDD as opposed to an SSD, you could have files on different platters, heads, sectors, etc, and depending how much load you put on an I/O bound resource, the overall operation takes more time since the drive has to seek data all over the place. Plus, random access on an HDD is abysmal.

Comment: @TevinMosley No prob. If these answers helped, please consider upvoting them and "accepting" one.

Comment: You probably want to also add /Q and /F to the DEL command so that it runs quieter and will also nuke read-only files.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try it this way:

```
DIR C:\*.txt /S /B > filelist
FOR /f %%i in (filelist) DO ECHO DELETE %%i
```

Remove the 'ECHO' when you are sure you want to run this ;-)

But this only makes sense when you want to process each file separately, for logging purposes for example. If not, then @Dogbert solution is shorter.

Comment: Thanks I'm saving this one